# Integrating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-1}{2}(x+is)^2}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I found this question from an old complex analysis exam in 2018. We have to calculate the following integral,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-1}{2}(x+is)^2}dx.$$
I would like to calculate it and I end with $\sqrt{2\pi}$ but I didn't use the methods from complex analysis but other methods.

As I can see, we don't have poles for this one, so I'm stuck. Do we have to use a sneaky trick or multiply with something in order to use methods from complex analysis?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Shift the path of integration to the real axis (i.e., $s$ becomes $0$). By Cauchy's theorem, the value of the integral will not change.

Comment: Cauchy's theorem is not what justifies it, but rather a change of variable $y=x+is$. Even if the integrand were not analytic one can still do the same substitution and get an equality with the new integral.

Comment: I think Euler's identity an be used to good effect here.

Comment: @plop What will the range be for $y$ after that change? I assume that $x$ was running on the real axis.

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Comment: @plop My proposal was to shift the contour to the real axis, so it becomes the familiar, real Gaussian integral and the answer follows quickly. With your proposed substitution, the path of integration is still off the real axis (unless $s=0$). I just do not see how it helps.

Comment: Notice that
$\int_\mathbb{R} \exp(-\frac12(x+is)^2)\,dx=e^{\frac12s^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac12x^2}e^{-ixs}\,dx$. The integral $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac12x^2}e^{-ixs}\,dx=e^{-\frac12s^2}$ is the characteristic function of the standard normal distribution.